# Bizarre problem with Safari: I can't click links in youtube

Tags: safari, video, youtube, javascript

Whenever I click on a video, or really any link at all on youtube nothing happens. To follow a link I've been right clicking->open in new tab. I *think* this is being caused by some sort of inconsistency with what javascript libraries are installed and what youtube expects me to have. I'm running safari 12.1.2. The issue seems to stem from an uncaught error in the 'onYtNavigate_()' function. I've pasted the console output below. Any suggestions? I'd like to be able to click youtube videos again haha.

```
[Error] TypeError: b.getDebugString is not a function. (In 'b.getDebugString()', 'b.getDebugString' is undefined)
    onYtNavigate_ (desktop_polymer_inlined_html_polymer_flags.js:20896:298)
    (anonymous function) (desktop_polymer_inlined_html_polymer_flags.js:8578)
    dispatchEvent
    Bb (webcomponents-hi-sd.js:76:366)
    dispatchEvent (webcomponents-hi-sd.js:144:259)
    fire (desktop_polymer_inlined_html_polymer_flags.js:9134:238)
    onEndpointTap_ (desktop_polymer_inlined_html_polymer_flags.js:12129:178)
    (anonymous function) (desktop_polymer_inlined_html_polymer_flags.js:8578)
    dispatchEvent
    Bb (webcomponents-hi-sd.js:76:366)
    dispatchEvent (webcomponents-hi-sd.js:144:259)
    _fire$$module$third_party$javascript$polymer$v2$polymer$lib$utils$gestures (desktop_polymer_inlined_html_polymer_flags.js:8830:177)
    OFa (desktop_polymer_inlined_html_polymer_flags.js:8854:355)
    click (desktop_polymer_inlined_html_polymer_flags.js:8851)
    _handleNative$$module$third_party$javascript$polymer$v2$polymer$lib$utils$gestures (desktop_polymer_inlined_html_polymer_flags.js:8819:208)
```

Comment: Did you log out/restart your Mac? If so, does the problem still persist? Can you access YouTube with other browsers? If so, you may want to try [reinstalling Safari](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204416), by reinstalling macOS.

Comment: A safari update and computer restart did nothing to fix the problem. Google chrome does not seem to have the same problem.

Comment: Do you have any Safari Extensions installed?

Comment: I had an issue clicking onto video links from youtube search/main page, but not links to external sites. This issue was caused by an ad-blocker extension I had running. Could this be something that's affecting you?

Comment: @AVelj thanks after disabling my Adblock extension the youtube video links began working again. Now I have to figure out how to make it work without disabling it...

Answer (score -1):

DOWNLOAD THAT

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204036

It worked for me

Comment: YouTube doesn't use Java, how does this resolve the issue?

Comment: of course he uses it...read the question

Comment: The programming language in question is javascript, not java. Updating my java install install then restarting my browser did not fix the issue.